# Stop form from submitting when it doesn't validate

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

The validation works, and the alert pops up when the email address is not valid, but then it goes and submits it after you click 'Ok' anyway. How do I stop it from processing the action?

Code sample:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()" />

function validate() {
var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
if (!/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) {
  alert('Please enter a valid email address');
  return false;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `(.+){2,}` --- what does this part mean?

Comment: I got the regex from somewhere else, sorry, I don't know the specifics of it, only that it validates the email! My guess is that it's something like "must be something here, must be at least 2 characters"

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" />

Comment: So should I use `.+@.{2,}\..{2,}` instead of `(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}`?

Comment: @zenkaty: yeb, because the latter makes no sense. `(.+){2,}` --- this could only be written by a person who doesn't understand what he does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onclick="return validate();"
```

then `return true` if validation is successful and `false` if not...

you can also attach the validation to the form itself:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
```

or with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   // validate
});
```

Comment: Ooh I like the jQuery edit, might give that one a shot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind onsubmit event of the form tag i.e.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" >...</form>
```